# VB6 and SQL report in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba, vb6

I'm making an excel extract out of some data that I'm pulling from SQL Server. I came across a small issue that I would like to ask you guys how to proceed. Basically I'm running a report that will include ClientName and 5 answers.

```
Name....Q1....Q2....Q3....Q4
JOHN     1     2     2     2
```

The thing is, I need to display values 1-5 on the extract, but the values saved are 1801 - 1805. How should I manipulate the data for the extract. Should I just do a case statement inside my SELECT statement, something like...

```
Select FirstName, LastName, case when Q1 = 1801 then '1', when Q1 = 1802 then '2'....
```

the thing is i might have to do it for all questions....?

This report will be written in a VB6 application -- so what i'll do is pull this data, and then loop through each recordset and just write it all to excel.

Comment: I'd just include the case select as you loop through your recordset values for display, not in the actual select itself. eg `while not rs.EOF : strAnswer1 = rs.item(2) : select case strAnswer1`

Comment: @FatBoySlim7 Could you minus 1800 from the result?

Comment: No in this case I can't as it looks like one of the values gets saved as a 0 and it's 1806, so in this case it wont work. I'm doing it in the select statement, it's kinda long but i feel its easier that way because i don't have to manipulate it as i write it- just basically dump it to excel in a loop

Comment: If you' re looping through the data anyway, then putting the case select in the loop is probably easiest to debug.  However, if you use .CopyFromRecordset to put it into excel, then the SQL is necessary.

Comment: someone please answer the question so I can accept it

Comment: Like @GaryEvans mentions with minus 1800, is 1806 the only exception? If so, still doable in SQL which I would stay with instead of any looping. SQL Server has many tools with great db engine: `PIVOT()`, `APPLY()`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are intending to loop through the  recordset to display it, putting the case select in the SQL is unnecessary and will make it harder to debug. You are better off with your logic in vb.

However, as an alternative you can use the .copyfromrecordset function in excel to dump the whole recordset into a sheet. If you do this then you need the SQL to include the case select as it is more complicated to manipulate the recordset.